# Confusing Sed One-Liner in Makefile Tutorial

Tags: c, linux, makefile, sed

Can anyone explain this sed one-liner in English (the more detail, the better)?

```
@sed 's/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g' < $*.d > $@; \
             rm -f $*.d; [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@
```

It's part of this tutorial:
http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html

I have a non-constant set of source files and want to auto-generate my dependency tree, based on the contents (includes) spelled out in my source files.

I was following the tutorial pretty well up until that...

P.S. I have basic understanding of sed select/replace, but I'm confused by the matching string and all the layers of redirection....  I've also read through the makefile tutorial once so have basic knowledge of *standard* makefiles...

Comment: When testing this, temporarily remove the rm part or put an echo there to say something like I'd be removing now if I were in production mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The sed pattern will be processed by make first, so if the rule that it applies to is trying to build `foo.P` then `$@` will be translated to `foo.P` and `$*` to `foo`. This means that the actual sed command will be something like:

```
sed 's/\(foo\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o foo.P : /g' < foo.d > foo.P
```

`\(foo\)` matches `foo` exactly and sets the first replacement to what matches (i.e. `foo`) `\.` matches a literal dot and `[ :]*` matches any number of spaces and colons.

As you can see the `\1` replacement is a bit redundant as the matched string is fixed. This would have worked just as well.

```
sed 's/foo\.o[ :]*/foo.o foo.P : /g' < foo.d > foo.P
```

which could have been made from:

```
sed 's/$*\.o[ :]*/$*.o $@ : /g' < $*.d > $@
```

Comment: Great!  Thank you so much... I see the first `rm` removes `foo.d`... the second one it looks to me like it checks for `foo.P` and then removes it if it doesn't exist?  That doesn't make sense.  Can someone give me a brief explanation of how the `[conditional]||command` logic works in shell script?

Comment: `-s` also checks if the file is non-empty, not just existing, so if the file exists but is empty, it would be deleted.